# Electronic journals with 'print on demand'

Tags: publications

We're thinking of starting a journal for undergraduate research.  I'm vaguely aware that some electronic journals have a 'print on demand' capability, so that someone who wants a printed bound copy can get one.  Can anyone point me to a journal that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their [website](http://www.e-jams.org/), the "Journal of Academy of Medical Sciences, a publication of Osmania Medical College, is a peer-reviewed online journal with Quarterly print on demand compilation of issues published."

Comment: Using a search engine with the terms "journal" and "print on demand" will yield more results: Journal of Cranio-Maxillary Diseases (craniomaxillary.com), Journal of Basic and Clinical Reproductive Sciences (jbcrs.org),   
Advanced Biomedical Research (advbiores.net), Indian Journal of Otology (indianjotol.org), Journal of Clinical Neonatology (jcnonweb.com), Avicenna Journal of Medicine (avicennajmed.com), Tropical Parasitology (tropicalparasitology.org), Indian Journal of Oral Sciences (indjos.com), Thyroid Research and Practice (thetrp.net), Imam Journal of Applied Sciences (e-ijas.org), etc

Answer (score 7):

It hasn't begun operating yet, but Cambridge University Press's [Forum of Mathematics](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displaySpecialPage?pageId=3896#.UA74BTGe66A) will work that way.  The journal will launch later in 2012.

Answer (score 3):

Journals of the American Diabetes Association (found this through the second hit via Google):

http://www.diabetesjournals.org/site/misc/AdvertisingRates.xhtml

Answer (score 1):

I don't think American Journal of Neuroradiology does this yet, but here is [an editorial](http://www.ajnr.org/content/30/1/1.full) from their Editor-in-Chief, discussing the merits of such a system.